# Using IntelliJ 11 Community Edition with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 11 Community Edition for a project that is in Mercurial (but not at the root of the repository). I integrated the project with Mercurial in the VCS menu, and all the options are now available. However, they don't seem to do anything. The only thing that seemed to do anything is to pull from the server. It doesn't show changed files, commit doesn't do anything. When I deleted a file I got this error message:

```
hg remove --after src/stats/KolmogorovSmirnovStatistic.java
abort: repository /home/ga1009/PhD/cpp/pmi/java not found!
```

the root of the repository is `/home/ga1009/PhD`. How can I get it configured?

I am using Debian Linux is it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a ticket on the official site and got a solution that seems to work:

> Go to Settings | Version Control and map the repository root to the
>   Mercurial VCS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Mercurial is supported in the community edition:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC

Sorry, I use Subversion.  But when I do, I have to check out the project from Subversion in order to get a working copy.  Did you do that with Mercurial?  Or are you working with your original files?

I'd do this:

1. Back up your original source.  God forbid you should lose a repository named "PHD".
2. Check the code into Mercurial.  Make sure you can see it in the browser.
3. Blow away your original source.
4. Open IntelliJ and check out from Mercurial.

You should be able to see changes added to the change list as you work.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - my code is checked out (using command line) - I checked it out before I created this project. All the relevant files are checked in to mercurial (again using command line). The only think I don't know how to do is tell IntelliJ the correct configuration so that the operations don't fail.

Comment: Don't use the command line; use IntelliJ.  It's the best SCM client there is.  I use it exclusively for SVN.

Comment: I also use it successfully with SVN, but for this project I have to work with Mercurial. And I can't make these two work together :(

Comment: I'd check out, modify, and commit within IntelliJ.  You should see your changes in the change list as you make them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the .idea/vcs.xml file to get it working.
The VcsDirectoryMappings needs to read something like:

```
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$/.." vcs="hg4idea" />
  </component>
```